# How do I pass an object containing property names & values to Gremlin property() step?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gremlin, amazon-neptune

According to [Gremlin 3.6 Release Documentation](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/CHANGELOG.asciidoc#tinkerpop-360-release-date-april-4-2022):

> - TINKERPOP-2665 Add the ability for property() to take a map
>   [...]
> - Extended property() to allow for setting a Map of property values.

And [Practical Gremlin](https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#tp36intro) by Kevin Lawrence:

> The property step can now be given a map of key/value pairs so that several properties can be created at once.

However, using JavaScript gremlin 3.6.1 with a target Amazon Neptune database, I have been unable to find the magic sauce that allows this to happen.

I expect the ability to add multiple properties at the same time using a single property() step and a JS object or array ('map' equivalent). My use case includes a set of variable properties in a JS object, and adding them in an external (JS for/of) or internal (gremlin-based) loop seems kludgy

I have tried the following (I am omitting the prefix steps `await g.addV('Label')` and the suffix steps `.next()`:

1. `.property(gremlin.process.cardinality.list, ['city': 'santa fe', 'state': 'new mexico'])` - lifted from TinkerPop docs, generates expected syntax error
2. `.property(gremlin.process.cardinality.list, {'city': 'santa fe', 'state': 'new mexico'})` - InternalFailureException (null: .property(Cardinality, LinkedHashMap))
3. `.property({'city': 'santa fe', 'state': 'NM'})` - InternalFailureException (Could not locate method: NeptuneGraphTraversal.property(LinkedHashMap))
4. `.property(['city', 'state'], ['santa fe', 'NM'])` - UnsupportedOperationException (java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String)

I realize there may be ways to accomplish this without this feature, but I want to use this feature if possible.

Comment: Neptune does not yet support TinkerPop 3.6.  Current support is at 3.5.3 with the latest Neptune Engine version.